# How to assign different length columns values of a data frame to another data frame with NAN values in different columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataset like this:

```
df1:
A    B    C
a    b    2
c    d    3
e    f    4
```

and another dataset

```
df2:
A    B    D
a    b    11
e    f    13
```

I want to add column D with df1 and want to replace with none values if the columns doesn't match. 
for exameple:

```
df3:
A    B    C    D
a    b    2    11
c    d    3    NAN
e    f    4    13
```

How to do this ?

Comment: You mean `df1.merge(df2, how='outer')`?

Comment: No, I want to do like df1['D']=df2['D']
It will assign if rows doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

You should set the first column as the index in both dataframes:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('A')
df1['D'] = df2.set_index('A')['D']
df1 = df1.reset_index()
#A  B  C     D
#a  b  2  11.0
#c  d  3   NaN
#e  f  4  13.0
```